# Making Microsoft Equation Editor Integral Signs

Tags: math-mode, equations

I tried searching for an answer to the question, but couldn't quite get what I want.

I would like to recreate the integral symbol from Microsoft Equation Editor 3.0 (also known as MathType) in XeLaTex, but I don't know how to do it. (See the image for more info) I'm using the fontspec package and unicode-math.

I have found that the integral symbol is the Unicode integral character ∫ in Times New Roman. However, I don't know how to incorporate this into an equation.

Could you please tell me how I can recreate this equation (exactly)? Thank you in advance.

[image: Microsoft Equation Editor Symbol]

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[30pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
The integral character is ∫.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: integral sign that I want]

which is the integral sign I want.

Comment: Do you know what font MS Equation 3.0 uses?

Comment: @HenriMenke It uses Times New Roman, as I said above.

Comment: Off-topic: In fine math typesetting, don't use `*` to denote the (binary) multiplication operator. Instead, if you really must an operator symbol at all, do employ either `\cdot` or `\times`.

Comment: Note that you won’t get the math-mode integral sign unless you type `$∫$`,

Comment: @Davislor However, the integral sign I want is one that is not inside math-mode but in normal text. The math-mode integral produces a slanted integral, which is not identical to that of MS Word.

Comment: That’s because you didn’t `\setmathfont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load individual math symbols and letters from TImes New Roman with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  I took all others from TeX Gyre Termes Math, including the missing `\cdot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Treat missing characters as errors!
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range={
  up, \int}] % Add any nother missing characters here.
\setmathfont{Times New Roman Italic}[range=it]

\begin{document}
\[
\int_5^6 \frac{x\cdot\cos x}{x\cdot\frac{y}{k}}dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn’t get you a properly-scaling integral, because TImes New Roman doesn’t have a math table, so you might want to leave `\int` out of rhe `range=` list.  You could also use the font from previous versions of Equation Editor, Cambria Math.

Although this uses the same fonts, you will get slightly-different layout in the two programs.

Another upright integral matching Times that you might try is

```
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C},
  StylisticSet=8]
```

or

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C},
  StylisticSet=8]
```

If you really, truly want to use an asterisk instead of `\cdot` or `\times`, change `\cdot` to `\ast`.

Answer (score 2):

The Tex Gyre Termes (text) and TeX Gyre Termes Math (math -- what else?) OpenType  fonts may come close enough to qualify as a match.

[image]

Note that the following test program requires compilation under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_5^6 \frac{x\cdot\cos x}{x\cdot\frac{y}{k}}dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there any way to exactly recreate it? I have edited the problem description for more information.

Comment: Could You be satisfied with these integrals at page 48 of this PDF in this site: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf